# How to separate TouchEvent from a MouseEvent in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, multi-touch

I am trying to use the Mouse and my TouchScreen pointers as independent devices.
I use a 10 points Ilyama touchscreen connected to my laptop.

Everytime I move my finger on the touchscreen, the mouse pointer moves to the location where I pressed the touchscreen. I don't want that at all!. I want my mouse to stay where it is.

Is there a trick to detect if a MouseEvent is generated by a TouchEvent? I could remember the last "MouseDevice" and differentiate it from a "MouseTouch".

Then I could programmatically set the MouseDevice position back to where it was as soon as a MouseDevice event comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to tell if a MouseEvent is coming from a TouchEvent.

> `Mouse events
>   Simulate mouse events enable an application to run on a device with a touch screen even if touch events are not handled by the application. Use the isSynthesized() method to determine if the mouse event is from a touch action. See Handling Mouse Events for an example.

If the MouseEvent  isSynthesized() then it comes from a TouchEvent.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/touch_events.htm) to get a full understanding.